# Existence of integrals for a particular set

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

This is more of a computational problem for multidimensional analsis, but I'm rather insecure about my approach.

I have the sets $A=\{(x,y)\mid x>0\,,x<y<2x\}$ and $B=\{(x,y)\mid x>0\,,x^2<y<2x^2\}$ with the function $f(x,y)=\frac 1{(y+1)^2}$. I am supposed to show that $\int_A f$ does not exist. but I've managed to show that it does...

My approach is to represent A as a union of compact rectifiable sets $$C_N=\{(x,y)|0<x<N,x<y<2x\}$$ where $C_N\subset C_{N+1}$ for all N. I know that  $\int_A f=\lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \int_{C_N} f$ if it exists. I've calculated that $$\int_{C_N} f=\int_N^{2N}\int_0^N\frac 1{(y+1)^2}\,dx\,dy=\frac{N^2}{(2N+1)(N+1)}$$
This would imply that it does exist since it converges as N goes to infinity...

Something is wrong here. Is it my choice of $C_N$? My integration? My entire approach maybe? Maybe the book? I was able to get $\int_B$ to converge just fine, but $\int_A$ doesn't seem to diverge as I'd like it to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\int_A f = \int\limits_0^\infty dx\int\limits_x^{2x}f(x, y)dy
$$

Take the first integral:

\begin{align}
\int\limits_x^{2x}\frac{1}{(y + 1)^2}dy =&\ -\left.\frac{1}{y + 1}\right|_x^{2x} = \left.\frac{1}{y + 1}\right|_{2x}^x = \frac{1}{x + 1} - \frac{1}{2x + 1}\\
=&\ \frac{1 + 2x - x - 1}{(x + 1)(2x + 1)} = \frac{x}{(x + 1)(2x + 1)}
\end{align}

You must now take the intgral:

$$
\int_A f = \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{x}{(x + 1)(2x + 1)}dx
$$

This will clearly diverge because it can be compared to an integral of the form:

$$
\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{1}{x}dx = \lim_{x_0\rightarrow \infty} \ln(x)\Big|_0^{x_0}
$$

**Edit: Taking the Integral**

If you want to get down to it, you really should actually take the integral:

\begin{align}
\int\limits_0^h \frac{1}{x + 1}dx - \int\limits_0^h \frac{1}{2x + 1}dx =&\ \ln(x + 1)\Big|_0^h - \frac{1}{2}\ln(2x + 1)\Big|_0^h \\
=&\ \ln(h + 1) - \frac{1}{2}\ln(2h + 1)\\
=&\ \ln\left(\frac{h+1}{\sqrt{2h + 1}}\right)
\end{align}

It should be clear that the limit as $h \rightarrow \infty$ results in the natural log diverging (as its argument goes towards $\infty$).